# Convert array of timestamp to MongoDB ObjectId using PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

I am using third party API to get value from MongoDB using PHP. I get Mongo ObjectId as array of timestamp as below. How I can convert it to original MongoDB ObjectId

```
Array(
        [timestamp] => 1573559942
        [machineIdentifier] => some value
        [processIdentifier] => some Value
        [counter] => 8306872
        [date] => 2019-11-12T11:59:02.000+0000
        [time] => 1573559942000
        [timeSecond] => 1573559942
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code might solve your problem.

```
$key = '';
$key .= dechex($arr['timestamp']&0xffffffff);
$key .= dechex($arr['machineIdentifier']&0xffffffff);
$key .= substr(dechex($arr['processIdentifier']&0xffffffff),-4);
$key .= dechex($arr['counter']&0xffffffff);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This seems like a valid answer, but please don't post code only answers. For example here it would be nice to cite the source of your algorithm. Please also see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer